# how to write query like this table structor?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

collection_info

```
+------------+--------------+
| id         | bigint(20)   |
+------------+--------------+
| name       | varchar(255) |
+------------+--------------+
| is_private | tinyint(4)   |
+------------+--------------+
| heart      | bigint(20)   |
+------------+--------------+
| created_at | datetime     |
+------------+--------------+
| updated_at | datetime     |
+------------+--------------+
| user_name  | varchar(255) |
+------------+--------------+
```

collection_game

```
+--------------------+--------------+
| game_slug          | varchar(255) |
+--------------------+--------------+
| collection_info_id | bigint(20)   |
+--------------------+--------------+
| created_at         | datetime     |
+--------------------+--------------+
```

game

```
+-----------+--------------+
| id        | bigint(20)   |
+-----------+--------------+
| name      | varchar(255) |
+-----------+--------------+
| slug      | varchar(255) |
+-----------+--------------+
| image     | varchar(255) |
+-----------+--------------+
| genre     | varchar(100) |
+-----------+--------------+
| publisher | varchar(255) |
+-----------+--------------+
```

[collection_info] 1 : N [collection_game] N : 1 [game]

About collection_info based on collection_info and

I'd like to bring three images from the game and print them out in a single line using the '' delimiter in the image column.

example like this :

```
+------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------+
| name       | is_private | heart | image                               |
+============+============+=======+=====================================+
| info-name1 | 1          | 2     | game-image1,game-image2,game-image3 |
+------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------+
| info-name2 | 0          | 4     | game-image1,game-image2,game-image3 |
+------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------+
| info-name3 | 0          | 6     | game-image1,game-image2,game-image3 |
+------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------+
```

How should I fill out the query?

Comment: how this tables are connected?

Comment: you mean this? [collection_info] 1 : N [collection_game] N : 1 [game]

Comment: I have provided the solution let me know if it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, You might need to change as there was no example data so did not get a chance to test it.

```
select
    ci.id,
    is_private,
    heart,
    group_concat(image, ', ') as image
from collection_info ci

join collection_game cg
on ci.id = cg.collection_info_id

join game g
on cg.game_slug = g.slug

where image in ('game-image1' ,'game-image2' ,' game-image3')

group by
    ci.id,
    ci.name,
    heart
```

Comment: it's work ! thank you but i wont get only three image how can i get only three image?